# Allow User's to clear print queue for themselves but not other users?

Tags: network-share, windows-10, printing, shared-printers

From what I understand, enabling allow on "manage documents" on the printer security tab will allow users to clear the queue for themselves and others... Is there a way to have them retain this ability for their own jobs but restrict them from deleting jobs from other users?

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

By default "CREATOR OWNER" is granted the right to "Manage documents" on childs objects only.

Childs objects are print jobs, thus, users can delete their own jobs only. So, it works as you describe it.

Here is what it looks like (Permissions on the queue):

[image: Creator owner permissions on the queue]